# Signin, Signup function of my website not working

Tags: php

I have a file `newnavbar.php` containing

```
$('#signUpSubmit').click(function() 
{
    $('#signUp').modal('toggle');
    //alert("signup completed");
    var email=document.getElementById('signUpEmail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'signUp.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: email,
            password: password
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('Email Sent');
        }               
    });
});
```

and `signUp.php`

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
include 'database.php';
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password= $_POST["password"];
echo "before signup called";
$value = signup($email, $password);
/* echo "value=$value"; */
if($value==1)
{
    echo '<script>alert("signup successful");</script>';
  //header("Location:test.php?signupValue=1");
}
else
{
    echo '<script>alert("signup failed");</script>';
}

?>
</body>

</html>
```

`signup` method return 1 on success and 0 otherwise.`signup` function defined in `database.php`

ajax success function executed but this not shown the success or failure message written in the `signup.php`. Why this not shown?

**Edit**

`signup` method just insert the record in database and return 1 on success and 0 otherwise. And I am sure that `signup` method works, because I checked the database after signup, and database is updated.

**Edit 2**

May be some are confused what I want to do. I need to show a alert on success or failure with appropriate message.

Comment: If `signUp.php` is not viewable, meaning it is just done through AJAX, then you don't need the HTML tags.

Comment: Where is `signup();`?

Comment: there's too much code missing and too many unknowns.

Comment: @Script47 I delete this but no improvement.

Comment: `success: function()` missing something here like `data` as in `success: function(data)` so you can access the response from the ajax request.  It's not magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, where to start

> the success or failure message written in the signup.php. Why this not shown?

For one thing, your not doing anything with the return

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'signUp.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        email: email,
        password: password
    },
    success: function() {
        alert('Email Sent');
    }               
});
```

You should have something like

```
 success: function(data){
      $('body').append(data);
 }
```

However you'll want to get rid of this `echo "before signup called";` and any other output from that script. Oh and

```
<html>
    <body>  
<?php
```

Does count as output, and will probably mess your page up.

In other words it just doesn't magically get appended to the DOM, you have to tell it to do something in the Ajax callback and you have to come out of the end of it with valid HTML, you can just insert `<html>` tags inside the page and expect everything to be cool.

So yes this means you will either have to have 2 scripts that do this, one without the HTML in it, or break the `signUp.php` page up somehow so you can use it in both.  For example you can take that functionality, make a 3rd page from it and then include it in `signUp.php` with HTML and then include it in a 4th one that is for AJAX etc...

Comment: I don't understand what you want to tell me. See my **Edit 2** section.

Comment: Now, I understand your answer. echo result of `signup.php` file is send to success function automatically. Thank you.

Comment: No I completely understand what you want to do, when you make a request it returns a response, that response ( for ajax ), is just text, because it could be any number of things you are returning.  The browser just doesn't magically know what you want to do with that response.